# Listing processes by CPU usage percentage in powershell

Tags: powershell

How does one lists the processes using CPU > 1% by piping the output from `Get-Process` to `Where-Object`?

Complete beginner to powershell all i can think is something like this

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { CPU_Usage -gt 1% }
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried running your code (in the PowerShell console or ISE) ?

Comment: yes i have i am getting CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want CPU percentage, you can use Get-Counter to get the performance counter and Get-Counter can be run for all processes. So, to list processes that use greater than say 5% of CPU use:

```
(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples | Where-Object {$_.CookedValue -gt 5}
```

This will list the processes that was using >5% of CPU at the instance the sample was taken. Hope this helps!

Comment: this should be the answer, not mine. +1 anyways :-)

Comment: It is good working solution, but it will not work if you have multiple processes with same name.

Comment: @Rail Sure it will, you just have to change `'\Process(*)\% Processor Time'` to something like `'\Process(foo*)\% Processor Time'`. It will display them as `foo`, `foo#1`, `foo#2`, etc.

Comment: Note that if you have multiple processors, CookedValue can exceed 100% for any individual process as well as for the _total.

Comment: It's quite annoying that there's no ProcessId in the result.

Comment: @RossPresser It is. However, Get-Counter can accept multiple counters, so if also using the '\Process(*)\ID Process' counter the sample will contain the PID. The resulting Samples will also have the instance filled in via the Path like '\Process(someinstance)\countername', where all the values can be associated via instance with a little bit of extraction.

Comment: I'm new in PowerShell: with this command I get the processors list, not the processes list. Maybe I'm missing  something?

Comment: Ok I've fixed my issue: translation for Italy is '\Processo(<star>)\% Tempo processore'. I wrote '\Processore(<star>)\% Tempo processore' so I got processor list instead of processes list

Comment: @GiorgioCalzolato How did you find the syntax in your language? I have a German environment and it seems to be the same as English, but my counter doesn't find certain processes.

Comment: @Blaisem I've a IT-it setup in Windows installation. Translation for "process" is "processo" and not "processore" so I fixed my isse. I've not searched for specific localized syntax instructions. It was an attempt.

Answer (score 16):

There are several points to note here:

- first, you have to use the `$_` variable to refer to the object currently coming from the pipe.
- second, Powershell does not use `%` to express percentage -- instead, `%` represents the modulus operator. So, when ou want percentage, you have to transform your number by yourself by simply multiplying it by `0.01`.
- third,  the `Get-Process` cmdlet does not have a field `CPU_Usage`; a summary on its output can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849832.aspx). About the field `CPU` is says: *"The amount of processor time that the process has used on all processors, in seconds."* So be clear on what you can expect from the numbers.

Summarizing the command can be written as

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.CPU -gt 100 }
```

This gives you the processes which have used more than 100 seconds of CPU time.

If you want something like a relative statement, you first have to sum up all used times, and later divide the actual times by the total time. You can get the total CPU time e.g. by

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -expand CPU | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -expand Sum
```

Try to stack it together with the previous command.

Comment: Is there any way, by which we can get the CPU percentage used by a process. It should be the value that task manager shows in CPU % column.

Comment: The accepted answer brings some error. Your answer is better! ;)

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for a solution to get cpu, mem utilization by process. All solutions I tried where I would get the cpu but those numbers were not matching with taskmanager. So I wrote my own. Following will provide accurate cpu utilization by each process. I tested this on a I7 laptop.

```
$Cores = (Get-WmiObject -class win32_processor -Property numberOfCores).numberOfCores;
$LogicalProcessors = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -Property NumberOfLogicalProcessors).NumberOfLogicalProcessors;
$TotalMemory = (get-ciminstance -class "cim_physicalmemory" | % {$_.Capacity})

 

$DATA=get-process -IncludeUserName | select @{Name="Time"; Expression={(get-date(get-date).ToUniversalTime() -uformat "%s")}},`
  ID,  StartTime,  Handles,WorkingSet, PeakPagedMemorySize,  PrivateMemorySize, VirtualMemorySize,`
   @{Name="Total_RAM"; Expression={ ($TotalMemory )}},`
  CPU,
   @{Name='CPU_Usage'; Expression = { $TotalSec = (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds
     [Math]::Round( ($_.CPU * 100 / $TotalSec) /$LogicalProcessors, 2) }},`
   @{Name="Cores"; Expression={ ($Cores )}},`
   @{Name="Logical_Cores"; Expression={ ($LogicalProcessors )}},`
 
 UserName, ProcessName, Path |  ConvertTo-Csv
```

Or as `[pscustomobject]`:

```
$cpu   = Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -Property NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$mem   = (Get-CimInstance -class cim_physicalmemory | measure capacity -sum).sum
$epoch = get-date(get-date).ToUniversalTime() -uformat "%s"

get-process -IncludeUserName | 
% { 
  if ($_.starttime -gt 0) {
    $ts       = (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime -ea si).TotalSeconds
    $cpuusage = [Math]::Round( $_.CPU * 100 / $ts / $cpu.numberoflogicalprocessors, 2)
  } else {
    $cpuusage = 0
  }

  [pscustomobject] @{
    "Time"                = $epoch
    "Total_RAM"           = $mem
    "CPU_Usage"           = $cpuusage
    "Cores"               = $cpu.numberofcores
    "Logical Cores"       = $cpu.numberoflogicalprocessors
    "UserName"            = $_.username
    "ProcessName"         = $_.processname
    "Path"                = $_.path
    "CPU"                 = $_.CPU
    "ID"                  = $_.ID
    "StartTime"           = $_.StartTime
    "Handles"             = $_.Handles
    "WorkingSet"          = $_.WorkingSet
    "PeakPagedMemorySize" = $_.PeakPagedMemorySize
    "PrivateMemorySize"   = $_.PrivateMemorySize
    "VirtualMemorySize"   = $_.VirtualMemorySize
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Further improving earlier answers by adding dynamic detection of the number of logic cores so the percentage can be adjusted back to what us common mortals expect to see, where 100% means all of the CPU bandwidth of the machine, and there is no value greater than 100%. Includes a filter set at 10%, which one can adjust as appropriate. The assumption is that people will be interested in finding processes with high overload processor usage and not want to list the numerous idle processes of the machine.

```
$NumberOfLogicalProcessors=(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_processor | Measure-Object -Sum NumberOfLogicalProcessors).Sum
(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').Countersamples | Where cookedvalue -gt ($NumberOfLogicalProcessors*10) | Sort cookedvalue -Desc | ft -a instancename, @{Name='CPU %';Expr={[Math]::Round($_.CookedValue / $NumberOfLogicalProcessors)}}
```

Sample output:

```
InstanceName CPU %
------------ -----
_total         100
idle           100
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `Get-Counter`, you can also use `Get-WmiObect` to list and filter processes.

```
powershell "gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process -filter 'PercentProcessorTime > 1' | Sort PercentProcessorTime -desc | ft Name, PercentProcessorTime"
```

Alternatively, for `Get-Counter`, here is an example showing number format conversion to get rid of the annoying decimal places of the `CookedValue`.
In addition to filtering, this example also illustrates sorting, limiting columns, and output formatting:

```
powershell "(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').Countersamples | Where cookedvalue -gt 3 | Sort cookedvalue -Desc | ft -a instancename, @{Name='CPU %';Expr={[Math]::Round($_.CookedValue)}}"
```

`Get-Process` is not the right cmdlet as it doesn't provide instantaneous CPU utilization.

You can also get the total load for all processors:

```
powershell "gwmi win32_processor | Measure-Object LoadPercentage -Average | ft -h Average"
```

Or,

```
typeperf -sc 4 "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to Add my version of code just to assist anyone that is having trouble with the same issues.
I needed one that gave me the CPU and Memory and this my take on the subject. It can export over time if you setup a scheduled task in windows, and it appends to a CSV file output and you can get multiple processes.

```
    $Cores = (Get-WmiObject -class win32_processor -Property numberOfCores).numberOfCores;
    $LogicalProcessors = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -Property NumberOfLogicalProcessors).NumberOfLogicalProcessors;
    $TotalMemory = (get-ciminstance -class "cim_physicalmemory" | % {$_.Capacity})
    #EDIT the PATH for the CSV output to be located
    $PATH = "C:\temp"
    #You can add more processes here as variables or just CommaSeperate them like below
    $Process1 = 'explorer'
    $Process2 = 'chrome'

    Get-Process -Name $Process1,$Process2 | select @{N="TimeStamp";E={Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff'}},
      ID,  
      name,
      Handles,
      PeakPagedMemorySize,
      PrivateMemorySize,
      VirtualMemorySize,
      @{Name="Memory_MB"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.workingSet / 1mb),2)}},
      @{Name='CPU_Usage'; Expression = { $TotalSec = (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds [Math]::Round( ($_.CPU * 100 / $TotalSec) /$LogicalProcessors, 2) }},
      @{Name="Cores"; Expression={ ($Cores )}},
      @{Name="Logical_Cores"; Expression={ ($LogicalProcessors )}},
      Path | Export-Csv -Path "$PATH\CPU_MEMORY_$env:COMPUTERNAME.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I know this is above the OP's question and goes a bit further but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To invoke vs. multible servers in parallel, and return process, cpu usage, servername, and corecount the following works well.

It will take 10 samples over 10sec and average the value. You can change this with the MaxSamples parameter.

I reckon its a less elegant version of what Emrah Saglam is doing, i just get scared and confused by all his pipes :)

```
$allServers = "server1", "PC001", "server2"

#Change value of MaxSamples to the number of samples to take. Samples are taken in 1sec intervals
$CPUUsage = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $allServers -ScriptBlock {
    $counters = (Get-Counter "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -MaxSamples 10).CounterSamples | Sort-Object -Property CookedValue -Descending
    [int]$coreCount = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
    $counters | ForEach-Object {
        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CPU_PCT" -Value ([math]::Round($_.CookedValue / $coreCount))[0] -InputObject $_
        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Host" -Value ($_.Path -replace "^\\\\|\\process.*$","") -InputObject $_
        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CoreCount" -Value $coreCount -InputObject $_
    }
    $counters | Select-Object InstanceName,CPU_PCT,Host,Path,CoreCount
}

#Unhash to see all samples:
#$CPUUsage | Sort-Object -Property Host,CPU_PCT -Descending | Select-Object -Property Host,InstanceName,CPU_PCT,Path,CoreCount | Out-GridView -Title "CPU Usage"

#Group samples, add wanted values and take average. Add values to new object
$CPUUsageGrouped = $CPUUsage | Group-Object -Property InstanceName,Host
$CPUUsageGrouped | ForEach-Object {
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CPUavg" -Value (($_.Group.CPU_PCT | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / $_.Count) -InputObject $_
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CPUmin" -Value ($_.Group.CPU_PCT | Sort-Object)[0] -InputObject $_
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CPUmax" -Value ($_.Group.CPU_PCT | Sort-Object)[$_.Count -1] -InputObject $_
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Host" -Value $_.Group.Host[0] -InputObject $_
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CoreCount" -Value $_.Group.CoreCount[0] -InputObject $_
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "InstanceName" -Value $_.Group.InstanceName[0] -InputObject $_
}

#Sort the grid view with the build in search functions
$CPUUsageGrouped | Sort-Object -Property Host,CPUavg -Descending | Select-Object -Property Host,InstanceName,CPUavg,CoreCount,CPUmin,CPUmax | Out-GridView -Title "CPU Usage"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this for one process?

```
$sleepseconds = 1
$numcores = 4
$id = 5244

while($true) {
  $cpu1 = (get-process -Id $id).cpu
  sleep $sleepseconds
  $cpu2 = (get-process -Id $id).cpu
  [int](($cpu2 - $cpu1)/($numcores*$sleepseconds) * 100)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Counter "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples `
    | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 0 -and $_.instancename -notin "_total", "idle", "" -and $_.CookedValue/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS -gt 0} `
    | Sort-Object CookedValue -Descending `
        | Select-Object @{N="ServerName";E={$env:COMPUTERNAME}},
        @{N="ProcessName";E={
            $friendlyName = $_.InstanceName
            try {
                $procId = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessesByName($_.InstanceName)[0].Id
                $proc = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId =$procId"
                $procPath = ($proc | where { $_.ExecutablePath } | select -First 1).ExecutablePath
                $friendlyName = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($procPath).FileDescription
            } catch { }
            $friendlyName
        }},
        @{N="CPU_Percent";E={[System.Math]::Round(($_.CookedValue/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS), 2)}},
        @{N="TimeStamp";E={Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff'}} -First 10 `
 $Result
} 

# If you want to export result to your SQL Server table you can use DbaTools Powershell Modules.
$Result | Select -Property ServerName, ProcessName, CPU_Percent, TimeStamp | ConvertTo-DbaDataTable | Write-DbaDbTableData -SqlInstance $OutInstance -Database $OutDB -Schema dbo -Table WindowsTopCPUProcesses
```

Comment: when i set $ServerName to win32_computersystem.name on an AWS EC2 instance I get Access is Denied, PSRemotingTransportException