# Result from get-process is a different than within the Resource Monitor

Tags: powershell, process, get

I want to script a simple BenchMark and therefore I need to monitor Resource Data. So far so good for CPU, RAM.... Specially I need to monitor the "ctxgf.exe" (special in Citrix).

When I use the code I receive for CPU(s) the Value for Example "122,73"

`Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -like 'ctxgfx'}`

If I check the value in Resource Monitor I receive a Value between 1 and 2 percent.

When I Check the same code just check the process "iexplore" both values th same in PowerShell and Resource Monitor.

anyone a Idea?

Comment: `Get-Process` does not return CPU load but overall process CPU time in seconds.

Comment: It seems. I try to use now the procedure from Shani "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943928/listing-processes-by-cpu-usage-percentage-in-powershell" this will retrive the correct data. Just need to split it. Thanks!

Comment: I am still get different Values between TaskManager / Resource Manager AND PowerShell Script. Anyone knows how to collect the real values from cpu usage that are equal to the values from TaskManager?