# Top 10 process in %CPU utilization - Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, process

Need to use a command in windows powershell to get top 10 process in %CPU utilization. It should return me process name, %CPU and used memory order by %CPU, like task manager does.

How can I get this list in powershell?

I find this one

```
Get-Counter "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
  | select -ExpandProperty CounterSamples `
  | where {$_.Status -eq 0 -and $_.instancename -notin "_total", "idle"} `
  | sort CookedValue -Descending `
  | select @{N="Name";E={
        $friendlyName = $_.InstanceName
        try {
            $procId = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessesByName($_.InstanceName)[0].Id
            $proc = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId=$procId"
            $procPath = ($proc | where { $_.ExecutablePath } | select -First 1).ExecutablePath
            $friendlyName = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($procPath).FileDescription
        } catch { }
        $friendlyName
    }},
    @{N="CPU";E={($_.CookedValue/100/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).ToString("P")}} -First 10 `
 | ft -a -HideTableHeaders
```

But, it is not working when insert memory info in Kbytes

Comment: Cool. What's your question?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I would like to know how can I get the list specified above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943928/listing-processes-by-cpu-usage-percentage-in-powershell ...Does this help ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar not at all

Comment: You can get it by writing some code... StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a free script vending machine. Try solving the problem on your own, feel free to come back and ask questions about specific problems you encounter along the way.