# Powershell script to list running processes and CPU utilization using Get-Counter is not returning all processes

Tags: powershell, windows-10, windows-11, powershell-7.0

I [found the following PS command](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba19a65b-d127-44e6-b088-5ffc50f5b4d7/need-powershell-script-to-get-top-5-cpu-along-with-idname-amp-username-as-similar-to-task-manager?forum=winserverpowershell) to list running processes sorted by CPU utilization:

```sh
Get-Counter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | 
    Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue | 
    ? {$_.instanceName -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} | 
    Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending | 
    Select-Object -First 10 | 
    ft InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).toString('P')}} -AutoSize
```

Below is the output, which appears it could be accurate, however while this ran my Antimalware Service Executable was using about 8% CPU.  Why is this not showing up in the PowerShell output?

```
InstanceName          CPU
------------          ---
msmpeng               0.39%
slack                 0.19%
taskmgr               0.19%
pwsh                  0.10%
todo                  0.10%
dwm                   0.10%
system                0.00%
creative cloud helper 0.00%
adobe desktop service 0.00%
adobeipcbroker        0.00%
```

Edit: The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023818/14903754) gives similar results.  Here is my adaptation of the answer (so it outputs it to a table instead of CSV)

```
$Cores = (Get-WmiObject -class win32_processor -Property numberOfCores).numberOfCores;
$LogicalProcessors = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -Property NumberOfLogicalProcessors).NumberOfLogicalProcessors;
$TotalMemory = (get-ciminstance -class "cim_physicalmemory" | % {$_.Capacity})

get-process -IncludeUserName | select @{Name="Time"; Expression={(get-date(get-date).ToUniversalTime() -uformat "%s")}},`
  ID,  StartTime,  Handles,WorkingSet, PeakPagedMemorySize,  PrivateMemorySize, VirtualMemorySize,`
   @{Name="Total_RAM"; Expression={ ($TotalMemory )}},`
  CPU,
   @{Name='CPU_Usage'; Expression = { $TotalSec = (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds
     [Math]::Round( ($_.CPU * 100 / $TotalSec) /$LogicalProcessors, 2) }},`
   @{Name="Cores"; Expression={ ($Cores )}},`
   @{Name="Logical_Cores"; Expression={ ($LogicalProcessors )}},`
 UserName, ProcessName, Path | Sort-Object -Property CPU -Descending | Format-Table -Property ProcessName, CPU | Select -First 10
```

And here are the results:

```
ProcessName                                          CPU 
-----------                                          --- 
SearchIndexer                                 2898.21875 
MsMpEng                                        1395.9375 
System                                              1045 
MsSense                                       612.359375 
explorer                                      507.296875     
OneDrive                                      467.296875 
OUTLOOK                                       362.765625 
SenseNdr                                        355.8125
```

After some tests, these results are actually worse. I ran a CPU intensive App and it shows up with the first (original) method, but it shows 1.5% even though Task Manager shows 25%. The second method, from the other SO answer, does not show the process at all.

Comment: After some more testing it looks like the numbers are just completely wrong.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023818/14903754) claims to give accurate info

Comment: Updated post.  After some tests, these results are actually worse. I ran a CPU intensive App and it shows up with the first (original) method, but it shows 1.5% even though Task Manager shows 25%. The second method, from the other SO answer, does not show the process at all.

Comment: You're grabbing the wrong property, aren't you after the usage? It should be: `... | Sort-Object -Property CPU_Usage -Descending | Select ProcessName, CPU_Usage -first 10`. Nonetheless, I once tried to do the same thing a while back. Not sure what I ended up with. Got pointed to some links on how task manager works and don't recall after that.

Comment: `CPU_Usage` does make the second results look more like the first results, but they are still inaccurate.

Comment: I'm now running NTOP (https://github.com/gsass1/NTop) and it is reporting the same, incorrect, values. I'm running a Unity program that Task Manager shows using 18% CPU and NTOP shows 1.3%, just like the powershell commands above.  I'm so confused.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gyApdCS

Comment: The issue is that it's grabbing the value of that moment and time, not much the average like TaskManager. `$cores = (gcim Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors;
(Get-Counter "\Process(*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples | ? InstanceName -NotMatch '_total|idle' | sort CookedValue -Descending | Select InstanceName, @{Name="CPU %";Expression={[math]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $cores), 2)}} -First 10`, this is probably as close as i could get it to mine. Interesting topic though. May have to turn to P/Invoke with other languages to get that info.

Comment: I really don't think it's an issue of TaskManager averaging over time. I have tested this pretty extensively with multiple different tools. I'm now even using PerfMon and seeing the same behavior. Task Manager just consistently shows MORE, even if you launch the process at the same time and watch in multiple different tools. I have started  a post in SuperUser as this doesn't seem to be a programming problem in any way. https://superuser.com/questions/1741387/task-manger-vs-performance-monitor-cpu-usage-why-are-they-so-different