# How to display CPU percentage % with process name and ID

Tags: powershell

I want to display the CPU% with the ID, NAME and CPU% only.

Below is my code:

```
Get-Process | Sort-Object CPU -Desc | Select-Object ID, Name, CPU, @{Name='ThreadCount';Expression ={$_.Threads.Count}} -First 10
```

I want to display CPU %

```
   Id Name            CPU ThreadCount
   -- ----            --- -----------
 8392 msedge   464.734375          27
14476 msedge       424.25          43
10328 explorer   379.5625          68
10772 msedge   339.921875          54
13632 OneDrive 256.828125          35
10544 Teams     172.46875          46
 9900 OUTLOOK  171.890625          79
10360 SynTPEnh 109.609375          11
22652 Teams     93.515625          21
14488 msedge    70.484375          15
```

I want to display the CPU in percentage.

Comment: No, I already checked this but was not able to get the answer that I needed.

Comment: See following : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fadd91ba-b0cc-4772-bb18-7052b3769c86/cpu-percentage?forum=winserverpowershell&force_isolation=true

Comment: [`$NumberOfLogicalProcessors = (Get-CimInstance -class win32_processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors; Get-Process |Select -Property @{ n='CPU%'; e={ [Math]::Round( $_.CPU * 100 / (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime -ea si).TotalSeconds / $numberoflogicalprocessors, 2) } }`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023818/1701026)